# google-api-python-client sample code gives 'module object has no attribute socket'

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

When trying to activate sample code from the [Latitude example](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/latitude/latitude.py) in google-api-python-client I get the following error: "_webapp25.py:464] 'module' object has no attribute 'socket'".
The code is:

```
from apiclient.ext.file import Storage
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.ext.authtools import run
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id='SOME_CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret='SOME_CLIENT_SECRET',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/latitude.current.best',
    user_agent='lati-go/1.0')

storage = Storage('moderator.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
    credentials = run(FLOW, storage)
http = httplib2.Http(cache=".cache")
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build("latitude", "v1", http = http)
data = service.currentLocation().get()
```

The code that gives the error is *credentials = run(FLOW, storage)*.
The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__
  handler.get(*groups)
File "H:\cproj\workspace\latitudeReminder\src\lati.py", line 31, in get
  credentials = run(FLOW, storage)
File "H:\cproj\workspace\latitudeReminder\src\apiclient\ext\authtools.py", line 116, in run
  ClientRedirectHandler)
File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 405, in __init__
  self.socket = socket.socket(self.address_family,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'socket'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It would have been useful to post the traceback - that's always helpful information.

I would guess that your problem is that the example you post is for a command-line application, yet you're trying to use it for a web server authentication flow. Try importing `run` from `oauth2client.tools` instead.